# Try to make random height div's with img cover in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello i'm still learning js, I managed to make this site (see code below) but i run into a few problems.

1. The images in the div .frequencyItem need to be cover so they are inside the div from left to right, top to bottom without streching the images. i try to do thin in css but it do's nothing at all. Is this becouse i make the img in js?
2. As i mentioned above, the img need to be inside of the div, they seem to be outside of the div at the bottom.
3. The div's have a random height givven bij js. On hover they expand and after the hover they need to go back to the height the div had before hovering. so this is diferent for each div. So maybe there need to be something that check the height before hovering?

I hope someone can help me and learn me some new javascript things.
Thanks

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta content="charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/fav.ico">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>



  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/core.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/screen.css">


</head>

<html>

<body>



<div class="freqInner"> </div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*+++++++++++++ GENERAL ++++++++++++++*/

@font-face {
    font-family: Font1;
    src: url(../fonts/font.eot), url(../fonts/font.woff), url(../fonts/font.woff2), url(../fonts/font.otf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal
}


*:not(select){
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}


html,body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    background-color: black;
}

.freqInner{
    /*position: fixed;*/

}

.frequencyItem {

  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(255,255,255);
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 3;

  -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
  -moz-transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
  -ms-transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
}

.frequencyItem:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgb(222,222,222);
  /*height: 400px !important;*/

}

img{
  /*overflow: none;*/

  width: 100px;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){



    //divs maken
        var i = 0;
        while (i < 7) {
            $('.freqInner').append('<div class="frequencyItem"></div>');
            i++;
        };

    //id maken voor div
        var a=0;
    $('.frequencyItem').each(function(){
        a++;
        var newID='menu'+a;
        $(this).attr('id',newID);
        $(this).val(a);
    });

    //array img en in div id zetten
    var array_1 = ["http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/1", "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/2", "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/3", "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/4", "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/5"];
      array_1.forEach(function(value,index) {
        $('#menu' + index).html('<img src="' + value + '" />');
        // $(this).css("height", h);
      });


    //random height geven aan div class...
        $('.frequencyItem').each(function() {
            var h = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 30;
            $(this).css("height", h);


});

//hovertje
    $('.frequencyItem').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            height: 400
        }, 'fast');
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            height: 100
        }, 'fast');
    });



});
```

Comment: `div from left to right, top to bottom without stretching the images`, you seem to have conflicting requirements. How is it possible to cover a variable div for all of those dimensions without resizing the image? Cover stretches images beyond the containing div so I'm not sure that is what you want.

Comment: you can give your image a `height:100%;` since that is variable and `width: auto;` to prevent stretching. `cover` is for background so you would need to set `background: url(value)` in your loop to a div instead of the image.

Comment: To use `cover` like for image you would need something like `position: absolute` similar to this pen: https://codepen.io/ErwanHesry/pen/JcvCw, but it still stretches the image.